# Static array in C# ASP .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting a strange problem.

I have a static method which is in common DLL and returns a static array of countries from the database.

And using this common method, I am trying to fill a Drop down of Country.

So code will be as below.

In Common - Helper Class DLL code

```
public static string[] Countries()
    {

            string qry = "select * from Countries";

            Dataset result=SqlHelper.ExecDS(qry);
            countryArray = new string[100];
            //Filing country array
            return countryArray;
    }
```

In the current project

```
countryOptions = new string[100];
countryOptions = Common.Helper.Countries();
```

I know Drop Down should be bind with DS only but as his is in common DLL i cannot change this.

But now only problem I am facing is even if delete a row from Countries table it is effect is not coming in Countries array.

Common.Helper.Countries() is still returns that row. I have double checked that the row has been deleted but its effect is not coming. Can someone please help me with this??

Comment: _"Common.Helper.Countries() is still returns that row."_ so the whole dropdown part is irrelevant. Put a breakpoint in the `Countries()` method and check what data is returned from `SqlHelper.ExecDS()`.

Comment: sorry if i have missed this here .. Common is a different project and the project from which i am calling Countries method is a different project.    if i include the common project in my current project it works fine but when i just include the common DLL, it is not behaving correctly.

Comment: The problem is with array only i have tried multiple time on my local machine. The countries array is not retuned correctly. Moreover even if i drop whole country table from DB it still returns me Array with all data. It should give me an error.

Comment: _" if i include the common project in my current project it works fine but when i just include the common DLL, it is not behaving correctly"_ So there's another problem? Is the Common DLL perhaps using another app.config and loading its data from another database where you haven't removed the row? You really have to narrow this down to the Common project and step through the code to see what's happening.

Comment: no it is not like that .. we have configured project such a way that everything will use common connection.. i thin the problem is with static if i do change this to return  normal array .. it is not creating the problem but as i said I CAN NOT CHANGE COMMON DLL. so does anyone have any idea why is it happening ?

Comment: _" i thin the problem is with static if i do change this to return normal array .. it is not creating the problem"_ Then show that code. How do you call the method when it's not static? You really have to show some effort because you're adding information in every comment. Your question should be clear, because this way nobody can do anything but guess.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually the problem was since array is static i must need to restart IIS otherwise it will take the same value.

Comment: No, that's not it. If you fill the array each time then static doesn't matter. But just use var arr =method() and don't preallocate 100

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> I know Drop Down should be bind with DS only
> ```

if you mean Drop Down list can only bind with `DataSet`, that is not correct. See [Binding DropDownList Using List Collection, Enum and DataSet in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/303564/Binding-DropDownList-Using-List-Collection-Enum-an)

> if I delete a row from Countries table it is effect is not coming in
>   Countries array

put a break point on the following line, see if the array is getting populated.

```
countryOptions = Common.Helper.Countries();
```

Call `dropDownList.DataBind();` to refresh the drop down list

Comment: The problem is with array only i have tried multiple time on my local machine. The countries array is not retuned correctly. Moreover even if i drop whole country table from DB it still returns me Array with all data. It should give me an error.

Answer (score 0):

How do you fill the array? I think this is where the error occurs.

Besides, your array does not need to be initialised twice:

```
// Creates a 100-item-array that is never actually used, so
// this line looks unnecessary
countryOptions = new string[100];

// Creates another array on the heap, leaving above array
// to GC
countryOptions = Common.Helper.Countries();
```